# npm run build fails after updating npm (EACCES: permission denied)

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I have a CRA (create-react-app) and I updated npm. Following, `npm run build` started to fail with error:

> EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'PATH/build/static/css'

My npm version is, `npm -v`:

> 7.22.0

And my scripts in `package.json` is:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  },
```

Running the command with sudo didn't help, before updating to npm (from version 6.X) this problem wasn't occuring.

Comment: Does the path `build/static/css` exist before running the script? If yes would it work if you removed it manually first?

Comment: It does exist. Yeah, it worked after removing it manually, and tried running the script again, no problem. I wonder what was the reason for it to happen at first tho.

Comment: might have been created under a different user (perhaps the older NPM version was running things as a different user than the newer one).

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. I feel like this is an answer more than a comment, so if you want feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept :) Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @apokryfos suggested, removing `build/static/css` manually and running build solves the issue.